# How to shuffle a sliding tile puzzle without making it unsolvable? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, shuffle, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm trying to figure out if there's a simple way to code a shuffling method/function in a sliding tile puzzle with 8 tiles, in Python 3. Here's what I mean.

Let's say this array represents our 9 squares, with 0 representing the empty space.

`puzzle = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]]`

I know there's a built-in shuffle() function in Python, but I cannot find information on whether it can be used to shuffle a 3x3 puzzle without making it unsolvable.

Comment: It can't shuffle a list and not make it "unsolvable" because there are varying definitions of "unsolvable"

Comment: Is it even possible to shuffle one of those puzzles to a point of being unsolvable? I'm not a mathematical genius, but I would opine you can always "unshuffle" something that is shuffled in a linear fashion.

Comment: I think (if Michael is not right), you need to define a function that performs a random valid move. Then you call that guy 1000 times.

Comment: What about generating a random sequence of moves such that you are simulating physically shuffling the puzzle. That way you will only shuffle it in ways that can be unshuffled (and you will have a solution ready-made) [crossed posts with @Dr.V - same idea]

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Yes, if the numbers are "shuffled" in the sense of being generated in a random order, the puzzle can end up being unsolvable. The idea is to start with the sorted list and move '0' around in random directions, a random number of times.

Comment: and now you want somebody here do code it for you??

Comment: @Dr.V No, I was looking for advice on how something like that can be accomplished in Python. Maybe there is some function for that which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this solution:

1. you do not need to juggle a multi-dimensional list
2. you can determine the amount of moves you want it to take
3. it should work on a puzzle of any dimensions - even unequal ones

The logic is very simple. `shuffle` runs for the amount of moves you designated, getting the pieces surrounding the empty at every iteration. It then randomly chooses a piece from the returned pieces and swaps the selected piece with the empty one. It is the program equivalent of manually scrambling one of these puzzles by hand. Considering it always makes a valid move the final scrambled puzzle should always be solvable.

`lastPiece` is used to make sure we don't undo the previous move. It simply stores the index of the last move and then gets removed from the choices on the next iteration.

**aside:**
I'm sure you will probably use a list of graphics in the long run. **Still use the numbers to get the shuffle**. Once the number list is shuffled you can iterate over it and assign graphics to each position based on the number. Shuffling graphics data is a lot more CPU intensive than shuffling numbers.

**edit:**
As a bonus I added in the solution and solution parser (`solve`). Gimme about another hour and I'll make your whole game! :D The solution is compressed. Instead of something like `[(2, 1), (1, 4), (4, 5)]` where each tuple equals `(to, from)`, since the `from` is always the next `to` (because `from` is the new empty index) we do this instead `[2, 1, 4, 5]` and juggle the compression in `solve`.

```
import random, math

def surroundingPieces(z, w, h):
    x = z%w
    y = math.floor(z/h)

    left  = None if x == 0 else z - 1
    up    = None if y == 0 else z - w
    right = None if x == (w-1) else z + 1
    down  = None if y == (h-1) else z + w

    return list(filter(None, [left, up, right, down]))

def shuffle(puzzle, moves, width, height):
    empty = puzzle.index(0)     #find initial empty index
    lastPiece = empty           #init lastPiece
    solution  = [empty]         #init solution

    for _ in range(moves):
        #get surrounding pieces
        pieces = surroundingPieces(empty, width, height)

        #remove the last piece we moved
        if lastPiece in pieces:
            pieces.remove(lastPiece)

        #select a piece
        pieceIndex = random.choice(pieces)
        solution.insert(0, pieceIndex) #insert move in solution

        #swap        
        puzzle[empty] = puzzle[pieceIndex]
        lastPiece = empty  #store this piece index

        puzzle[pieceIndex] = 0
        empty = pieceIndex #store new empty index

    return puzzle, solution

    
#this is the program equivalent of manually solving the puzzle
def solve(pzl, sol):
    for i in range(len(sol)-1):
        pzl[sol[i]]   = pzl[sol[i+1]]
        pzl[sol[i+1]] = 0
        
    return pzl

puzzle, solution = shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8], 10, 3, 3)

print(puzzle)                       #[1, 3, 0, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5]     
print(solution)                     #[2, 1, 4, 5, 8, 7, 4, 3, 6, 7, 4]
print(solve(puzzle[:], solution))   #[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: This is fantastic. At first, I thought it might be a bit too complex, but after a while I got it. I still have one question, however, if you don't mind. You mentioned the variable 'lz' is used to make sure that the next move doesn't undo the previous one. I cannot figure out how it accomplishes it though. Could you please clarify? I'm a newbie in programming.

Comment: @DeadManProp - I renamed and commented everything to be as clear as possible. I hope that helps. I also made a small change to the logic regarding how I ignore the last move.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort you've put into this answer! It was tremendously helpful in understanding the process :) No need to worry about the solution. I need to write an A-star algorithm for this.

Comment: @DeadManProp - You're welcome. It was fun! Regarding algorithm - Yes, you do. If you track the user moves against the solution it will probably be much easier to write that algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Slow method: Shuffle until you get a solvable puzzle

A `3X3` is not solvable if it has odd number of inversions. Flow this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293527/how-to-check-if-a-8-puzzle-is-solvable) for solvability of `3X3` puzzle.

### Code

```
def is_solvable(puzzle):
  p = puzzle[puzzle != 0]
  inversions = 0
  for i, x in enumerate(p):
    for y in p[i+1:]:
      if x > y:
        inversions += 1
  return inversions % 2==0

# Now lets generate until we get a solvable puzzle
while True:
  puzzle = np.random.choice(np.arange(9), size=9, replace=False)
  if is_solvable(puzzle):
    break

print (puzzle.reshape(3,3))
```

output:

```
[[8 3 4]
 [2 1 7]
 [5 6 0]]
```

Comment: I think its actually faster than moving randomly single moves. And .. if not solvable, one can just swap two entries, or am I wrong with that?

Comment: @Dr.V we have to make sure the swaps do not result in odd number of inversions which might become tricky as we start swapping more and more tiles.

Comment: @mujjiga Thank you! I think I will go with this method. I have a question, however. Why is the modulus result at the end of the is_solvable() function equated to 0? What happens if the modulus doesn't give 0 as a result? Also, I'm not familiar with specifying the list index as "puzzle[puzzle != 0]". Does it basically mean "assign all values of the list to variable 'p' except for 0"?

Comment: @DeadManProp if the number of `inversions` is even, then `inversions%2==0` will be True else it will be False. When calculating number of inversions we should not consider `0` because it is an empty tile, so we exclude exclude it from the existing shuffle before calculating number of inversions.

Comment: @mujjiga Ahh I see. I didn't consider the fact that the 'inversion%2==0' returns 'True' or 'False'. Thank you!